# Updating a variable from within another method objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm brand new to Objective C, XCode iOS so I'm starting with a simple counter app.

I've got the basics set up (incrementing the score on button press) but I can't seem to get the UILabel text to update, on each button press i.e. each time I increment `currentScore` it doesn't update the `currentScore` variable inside the `UILabel text`

```
#import "JPViewController.h"

@implementation JPViewController

int currentScore;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    //Init currentScore
    currentScore = 0;
    NSLog(@"Your score is %d", currentScore);
    
    //Points text label
    
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 290, 400)];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your score is: %d", currentScore];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    //TODO: Position points in centre.
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    
    //Add Points Button
    
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [button setTitle:@"Press Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button sizeToFit];
    button.center = CGPointMake(320/2, 60);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
 
}

- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
    currentScore++;
    NSLog(@"Your score is %d", currentScore);
    //TODO: Update the label with the new currentScore here.
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To used lable in side your button do following thing

1) Give tag to your label

```
 UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 290, 400)];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your score is: %d", currentScore];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    //TODO: Position points in centre.
    [label setTag:1000];//Give tag to your label 
    [self.view addSubview:label];
```

2) Then get label by it's tag in button method

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
    currentScore++;
    NSLog(@"Your score is %d", currentScore);
    UILabel *label = (UILabel) [self.view viewWithTag:1000]; // you get your label reference here
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormate:%d,currentScore]]; // then store your current score in your lable
    //TODO: Update the label with the new currentScore here.
}
```

Or this is second method

1) Make your UILabel variable global like below

```
 @implementation JPViewController
    {
          UILabel *label;
    }
```

2) in viewDidLoad()

```
label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 290, 400)];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your score is: %d", currentScore];
        [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
        //TODO: Position points in centre.
        [self.view addSubview:label];
```

3) In your button event

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
        NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
        currentScore++;
        NSLog(@"Your score is %d", currentScore);
        [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormate:%d,currentScore]]; // then store your current score in your lable
        //TODO: Update the label with the new currentScore here.
    }
```

Comment: For ever who visit this - don't use tags for this situation! Second approach seems more logical however 'label' is definitely not a global variable in any way.

Comment: @hris.to thanks for comment but can you say me why we not used tag? And if we dont used tag and want to access this label in button how it possible with out tag or not make it global?

Comment: Because you are making search of current view and all it's subviews until you find searched label which you can have on the fly. The big problem here is not even performance, but the readability of your code, as later someone will have to inspect all your tags and know what stands for each of them. By declaring @interface JPViewController{ UILabel* label; } you are indeed not making it global. It's not accessible outside of class(I won't go into KVO discussion which is highly objc specific) and this way your class is more object oriented.

Comment: ok i understand your point but for loop is take more time then tag that why i suggest the tag and if we build the enum of tag then any one used it with out doing any other thing

Comment: @hris.to i think setting tag to label is better and easy to implement. and it is faster also. so How you can say that using tag is not good.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a @property (class variable)

```
@property int currentScore

@implementation JPViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Init currentScore
    self.currentScore = 0;
    NSLog(@"Your score is %d", self.currentScore);

    //Points text label

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 290, 400)];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your score is: %d", self.currentScore];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    //TODO: Position points in centre.
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    //Add Points Button

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [button setTitle:@"Press Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button sizeToFit];
    button.center = CGPointMake(320/2, 60);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

}

- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
    self.currentScore++;
    NSLog(@"Your score is %d", self.currentScore);
    //TODO: Update the label with the new currentScore here.
}
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks. The only problem is I get an error "Unexpected @ in program" when I try create the `@property int currentScore`